# Error in numeric switch statement

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
head(df_final)
MATCHID COMPETITION            TEAM1              TEAM2 GOALS1 GOALS2 RESULT  EXPG1 EXPG2     DATUM     TIJD VERSCHIL  CLAS type           TYPE
1 1696873  Pro League   Standard Liège Sporting Charleroi      3      0    TEAM1  1.57  0.61 25-7-2014 18:30:00     0.96  0.96  TBD (-0.0767,1.54]
2 1696883  Pro League Waasland-Beveren        Club Brugge      0      2  TEAM2  1.29  1.18 26-7-2014 16:00:00     0.11  0.11  TBD (-0.0767,1.54]
3 1696879  Pro League           Lierse        KV Oostende      2      0  TEAM1  1.03  1.04 26-7-2014 18:00:00    -0.01 -0.01  TBD (-0.0767,1.54]
4 1696881  Pro League         Westerlo            Lokeren      1      0  TEAM1  1.76  1.24 26-7-2014 18:00:00     0.52  0.52  TBD (-0.0767,1.54]
5 1696885  Pro League    Cercle Brugge               Gent      0      0 GELIJK  1.24  1.27 26-7-2014 18:00:00    -0.03 -0.03  TBD (-0.0767,1.54]
6 1696877  Pro League         Mechelen               Genk      3      1  TEAM1  1.60  1.23 27-7-2014 12:30:00     0.37  0.37  TBD (-0.0767,1.54]
```

I want to would like to add one column called `RESULT_STRENGTH` that classifies the matches based on the column `VERSCHIL`.

If `VERSCHIL` is bigger than 0.3 `RESULT_STRENGTH` should be `HIGH`, if `VERSCHIL < -0.3` then `RESULT_STRENGTH` should be `MEDIUM` and if `VERSCHIL > -0.3 & <0.3` then `RESULT_STRENGTH` should be `LOW`;

I therefore wrote the following function:

```
classes <- function(df) {

 df$VERSCHIL <- as.numeric(df$VERSCHIL)
 AA <- df$VERSCHIL

 #create new column with default
 df$STRENGTH_TYPE <- "DEFAULT"

 switch(AA, 
     ">0.3" ={
       df$STRENGTH_TYPE <- "HIGH"
     },
     "<-0.3"={
       df$STRENGTH_TYPE <- "LOW"    
     },
     ">-0.3 & <0.3" ={
       df$STRENGTH_TYPE <-  "MEDIUM"
     }
 )
}
```

But when I run `classes(df_final)` I get the following error:

```
 Error in switch(AA, `>0.3` = { : EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

Any thoughts on what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Because `switch` just doesn't work that way (read `?switch` more carefully) ... ?

Try something like

```
AA <- c(-0.5,0,0.5)
cut(AA,breaks=c(-Inf,-0.3,0.3,Inf),
       labels=c("LOW","MEDIUM","HIGH"))
## [1] LOW    MEDIUM HIGH  
## Levels: LOW MEDIUM HIGH
```

(Use `as.character()` if you really don't want a factor ...)